# How to configure service endpoints for WCF service behind offloaded SSL with HTTPS in WSDL

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl, https, wcf-binding

My deployment environment has SSL-offloading (and load-balancing) hardware in front of my IIS 7.5 hosted WCF service.  So while the outside world will go to

```
https://mydomain.com/MyService.svc
```

the hardware will handle the SSL and forward the traffic to

```
http://myintranet/MyService.svc
```

---

However, when I grab the WSDL from the outside (by tacking on "?wsdl"), the WSDLs address are for "http://mydomain.com/MyService.svc" -- the insecure, non-SSL version of my public address.

I tried explicitly setting the listenUri, but I get an error because my site also requires multiple bindings (I internally can access it beyond the SSL-offloading but through the load-balancer, or bypass the load-balancer and reach the site(s) directly):

```
When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute.
```

I've tried numerous combinations of baseAddresses, prefix filters, multiple endpoints, etc. but always end up with one error or another.  Despite my best Googling, I can't find anyone else with this set up.

Comment: If you have the scenario of SSL offloading then its worth you consider having basicHttpBinding as the traffic between the load balancer and your web server would be behind your own firewall and secure. But if you have authentiation to be performed on username password consider checking out the clearusernamebinding that allows you to transport username passowrd over basichttpbinding: http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html

Comment: @Rajesh, I've actually already used an alternate strategy for SSL offloading (http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2006/09/26/how-to-ssl-passthrough-with-wcf-or-transportwithmessagecredential-over-plain-http/).  But I still want my generated WSDL to include an HTTPS endpoint URI, while my actual site needs to bind to several non-HTTPS names.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Has anyobd found a way to overcome this. I am facing the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I forgot I had asked this.  We did eventually arrive at a solution, though it has been so long, I can't remember all of the details.  Instead, I'm extracting information from our existing configuration that I believe are the key point.

Basically, we are using a "httpsViaProxyTransport" we created from sample code we found in the wild.  This convinces WCF that it's a secure transport even though it's really just HTTP.

Then within /configuration/system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment, we set some baseAddressPrefixFilters.  We set both HTTP and HTTPS because we sometimes access it behind out NLB/SSL-offloader.

```
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
          <add prefix="http://MyService.mydomain.com/"/>
          <add prefix="https://MyService.mydomain.com/"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
```

Answer (score 0):

We're having a hell of a time getting SSL offloading to work with WCF.  The problem is that the same config switch determines allowed protocol (which has to be http) and the protocol emitted in the proxy (which has to be https).  Our answer was to drop the SSL offloading requirement.  We may have given up too easily.

If you're more tenacious than us, you might consider trying a custom WSDL exporter, as documented [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4213c198-c4d8-46d9-b3a6-d89b726dbf70/machine-name-appearing-in-wsdl-instead-of-localhost?forum=wcf).